# Clipping MBTiles with BoundingBox

Tags: mapbox, mbtiles, node-js

I have a relatively large worldwide raster mbTiles file from which I want to convert individual countries into new mbtiles. Unfortunately I fail to use tilelive which is actually predestined for this purpose.

Has anyone ever run tilelive on an Ubuntu server and got the [tilelive-copy](https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive) command implemented?

I only get the error message.

I am going to do the following:

- installation of node js
- installation of npm
- `npm install tilelive`
- `npm install @mapbox/mbtiles`
- `npm install mbtiles`

After executing the command: `tilelive-copy input.mbtiles ouput.mbtiles` I only get the error message `Error: Invalid tilesource protocol: mbtiles`.

I have now tried different nodejs versions etc. Nothing leads to success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was ultimately a version problem.
With NodeJS V 9.11.1 64 bit everything was possible without problems.

So:

- Install NodeJS V 9.11.1 64 Bit
- install npm
- npm install -g @mapbox/tilelive @mapbox/mbtiles

and its works:

```
tilelive-copy --bounds="5.9559,45.818,10.4921,47.8084" 18.mbtiles switzerland_18.mbtiles
```